# Missing libraries in my RPM (but I know they are there)

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, lib

I have an RPM that I am trying to install in my VM. My RPM is named myPackage.rpm and when I try to install it (`yum install myPackage.rpm`), I am getting the following errors:

```
Error: Package: myPackage.x86_64 (/myPackage)
       Requires: libicudata.so.32()(64bit)
Error: Package: myPackage.x86_64 (/myPackage)
       Requires: libicuuc.so.32()(64bit)
Error: Package: myPackage.x86_64 (/myPackage)
       Requires: libicui18n.so.32()(64bit)
```

I did `rpm2cpio myPackage.rpm|cpio -idvm` to pull all the files from my rpm (in /root/rpms).

I did a find for libicudata.so*, and it shows the following:

```
/root/rpms/usr/lib64/libicudata.so.32.0
/root/rpms/usr/lib64/libicudata.so.32
/root/rpms/usr/lib64/libicudata.so
/root/rpms/usr/lib/libicudata.so.32.0
/root/rpms/usr/lib/libicudata.so.32
/root/rpms/usr/lib/libicudata.so

/usr/lib64/libicudata.so.32.0
/usr/lib64/libicudata.so.32
/usr/lib64/libicudata.so.50.1.2
/usr/lib64/libicudata.so.50
/usr/lib/libicudata.so.32.0
/usr/lib/libicudata.so.32
/usr/lib/libicudata.so.50.1.2
/usr/lib/libicudata.so.50
```

The files listed at `/root/rpms/usr/` are files from my rpm, the others are installed in the VM.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong and why. Am I packaging my RPM incorrectly?

Comment: What distribution does your VM use? I'm guessing CentOS, but I'm not sure. What does `yum whatprovides 'libicudata.so.32()(64bit)'` give? What about `rpm -qf /usr/lib64/libicudata.so.32`?

Comment: Centos 7.

rpm -qf /usr/lib64/libicudata.so.32 reports `file /usr/lib64/libicudata.so.32 is not owned by any package`. I am not running my VM with network access, so I cannot provide the output of `yum whatprovides`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error. All the library files for ICU were messed up before I created my RPM. I ran `ldconfig` and it gave me error messages similar to this:

`ldconfig: /lib/libicudata.so.32 is not a symbolic link`

Where I was building my RPMs, what was supposed to be the symbolic links were actually files that were *identical* to the lib they were supposed to be pointing to. So, I deleted what should have been the symlinks, and recreated them. This eliminated the error.

Answer (score 1):

1) rpm does not care what you have actually installed on your file system. If you somehow put there the libraries, then rpm does not care. Rpm only check the rpmdb.

2) The dependencies are just strings. So if rpm tell you that it requires `libicudata.so.32()(64bit)`. Then it does not check for 64 bits version of library namend libicudata. Rpm do only the simplest thing. Rpm check if some package provides this string. So check your package:

```
rpm -qp --provides ./foo.rpm
```

if it provides this string.

rpmbuild has built-in check, which can detect the presence the library and then automatically insert the provides:

```
Provides: libicudata.so.32()(64bit)
```

If you are absolutely sure that rpmbuild is incorrect, you can specify the provides manually.